# Inserting into Access database from NetBeans

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, netbeans, ucanaccess

I have created a GUI based Hotel Management System in java netbeans which is connected with Ms Access Database. In database, i have a table named "RoomInfo".

When i try to execute the following query, i get two kinds of errors.

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO RoomInfo(RoomNumber,Reserved,RoomCategory,AirConditioned,
    BedType, RentPerDay)VALUES("+objr.roomno+","+objr.reserved+","+objr.category+","
   +objr.AirConditioned+","+objr.bedtype+","+objr.rent+")";
```

First error is `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.7 unexpected token: ,` I get this error when i leave all the Jtextfields empty and try to insert new record in to the database.

Second Error is `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.7 user lacks privilege or object not found: Economy` (Economy is the entry for room category) I get this error when i enter data in to the Jtextfields and try to save it in to the database.

Need help identifying the problem.

Comment: Two problems: (1) You should be using question marks (`?`) as parameter placeholders in your SQL command text, e.g., `... VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)`. (2) You are doing your "None of the fields can be left empty" check *after* trying to insert the row, instead of before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of passing the the variable names directly into the sql string and then setting them again using ps.setString(); just use place holders in the sql string.
What I mean is

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO RoomInfo (RoomNumber, Reserved, RoomCategory, AirConditioned, BedType, RentPerDay) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?,?)";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        ps.setString(1, objr.roomno);
        ps.setString(2, objr.reserved);
        ps.setString(3, objr.category);
        ps.setString(4, objr.AirConditioned);
        ps.setString(5, objr.bedtype);
        ps.setString(6, objr.rent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So the syntax of my INSERT QUERY is wrong ?

Comment: Looks that way.